# How to listen to events to sort an array

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, optimization, typescript

I read [this](https://dev.to/abhinavmir/off-chain-sorting-over-on-chain-sorting-in-solidity-4of7) article on sorting an array off-chain using event listeners, but my array doesn't appear to be sorted in time when the array is called in typescript.

This is my contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.4;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;


contract Test  {


    uint256[] unsortedArr;

    uint256[] sortedArr;

    event sort(uint256[]);


    function addElement(uint256 element) public {
        unsortedArr.push(element);
    }

    function sortOffChain() public  returns (uint[] memory)
    {
    /*On the backend, the algorithm would look something like this -

    *event listener listening for sort()
    *calls sort function in typescript upon getting triggered
    *calls getSortedData() function with returned value of sort()
*/
        emit sort(unsortedArr);
        // I want sortedArr below to be sorted by the time the return is called
        return sortedArr;
    }
    
    function getSortedData(uint256[] memory sortedData) public 
    {
        sortedArr = sortedData;
    }


// for typescript test
function getUnsortedArr() public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return unsortedArr;
    }

function getSortedArr() public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
    return sortedArr;
}
}
```

This is what the event listener looks like in TypeScript:

```
async function main() {
;

// deploying
  const Test = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Test");
  const test = await Test.deploy();
  await test.deployed();
  console.log("Test deployed to", test.address);
// add elements to array
  await test.addElement(5);
  await test.addElement(3);
  await test.addElement(7);
  await test.addElement(2);
  await test.addElement(1);
  await test.addElement(9);
// event listener
const OffChainResult = await test.sortOffChain();
test.on("sort", (arr: []) => {
  let arrayForSort = [...arr];
  const sortedArr = arrayForSort.sort((n1: number,n2 : number) => n1 - n2);
  console.log("array sorted");
  test.getSortedData(sortedArr);
  console.log("getSortedData completed");
}
);
console.log("output of getSortedData:");
console.log(OffChainResult);
```

This is what comes out in the terminal when I run the script:

```
Test deployed to 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
output of getSortedData:
{
  hash: '0x40eeca2775e29300e51f3a067c99195f0cf33ee0aac73eaeaf05d826b41c3d4c',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: '0xd952eb1b086de3b1ee213fff01b464925670bc6d7e515ac3f7dad3b732471857',
  blockNumber: 8,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  confirmations: 1,
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { value: "1346048670" },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "1000000000" },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "1692097340" },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "29021272" },
  to: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
  value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  nonce: 7,
  data: '0xb8dbac2c',
  r: '0x621282eec4ac159b052250faa62aa5e954510ba91e841d3477bf0228ecf952d9',
  s: '0x7d36e86d604b58006dd918efc52babd3f3e61dd9f80e36fa2e3e8a9a03fe5298',
  v: 1,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 31337,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
array sorted
getSortedData completed
```

There are two issues: (1) `getSortedData()` which is called by `sortOffChain()` returns a value before the event listener gets a chance to sort the array and set `sortedArr` to the right value and (2) even if the array isn't sorted, `sortOffChain()` should return an empty array, not whatever the console output for `OffChain.

Is this just an issue with how I made the event listener? Do I need to put the lines of code in a different order? Also, what is the thing that the console output for `OffChainResult`.

I've also heard that the sorted array that is to be given to the smart contract can't be validated. How do I ensure that it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go through your code and I tested on my end too, and frankly, I learned a lot from this post. So to begin with, your contract is a little buggy. Since you want to catch the event, you don't need to return anything. Even if you do, you need to use `view` in your function. I modified the contract and it looks like this:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Sort {
    uint256[] unsortedArr;
    uint256[] sortedArr;

    event sort(uint256[]);

    function addElement(uint256 element) public {
        unsortedArr.push(element);
    }

    function sortOffChain() public {
        emit sort(unsortedArr);
    }

    function getSortedData(uint256[] memory sortedData) public {
        sortedArr = sortedData;
    }

    // for typescript test
    function getUnsortedArr() public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return unsortedArr;
    }

    function getSortedArr() public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return sortedArr;
    }
}
```

Moving on, you need to change the method to change the process of catching the event. I might have written the code differently. You can fix that on your end. It will be like this:

```
  function get1DArray(arr: any) {
    return arr.join().split(",");
  }

  it("Event get", async () => {
    let data = await sort.sortOffChain();
    let receipt = await data.wait();
    let finalEvent = receipt.events?.find((event) => event.event === "sort");
    let unsortedArray = get1DArray(finalEvent?.args);
    console.log("Unsorted Array: ", unsortedArray);

    const sortedArray = unsortedArray.sort((n1: number, n2: number) => n1 - n2);
    console.log("Sorted Array: ", sortedArray);

    console.log(
      "Previous Sorted array in contract: ",
      await sort.getSortedArr()
    );

    await sort.getSortedData(sortedArray);
    console.log(
      "New Sorted array in contract: ",
      (await sort.getSortedArr()).toString()
    );
  });
```

It would be best if you had this function `get1DArray` since `args` returns an array of an array. You will get a sorted array sorted off-chain using this.

Comment: This has worked great for me here, but I'm having trouble implementing this same off-chain computation with other off-chain computations. I tried using what you wrote here for another smart contract meant to track defaults, but I'm getting mixed results.  [Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/132678/how-to-delay-calling-functions-for-off-chain-computations) is my problem. Could you also try taking a look at this problem as well?